# Why would this code work locally but break online?

Tags: loop, localhost, local-installation

For some strange reason this code works perfect on my local installation of Wordpress yet when I put it live on a web server the code just repeats the same two articles over and over again and doesn't progress beyond the same two articles. I'm using InfiniteScroll (not the WP plugin, my manual installation of it). Is there anything wrong with my loop?

**EDIT**

Here's the link to code in full taken from single.php: http://pastebin.com/dtiSHUYP

```
<div id="post-wrap">


                <?php // Show all posts within this category
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args= array(
                    'category_name' => $cat->slug, 
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'cat' => '-12',
                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
                );
                query_posts($args); ?>

                <?php $current_post_date = $post->post_date; ?>

                <?php if( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php if ($post->post_date < $current_post_date) {  ?>

                <article>
                    <figure>

                      <?php
                          $image_link=get_post_meta($post->ID,'Image_Link',true);
                          if($image_link != '') {
                          echo '<a href="http://example.com">'. get_the_post_thumbnail() .'</a>';
                          } else {
                          echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
                          }
                      ?>

                      <figcaption>
                            <?php
                            // Call in the contents of a custom field called Credit and if custom field in admin panel is empty don't display <p> tags otherwise wrap contents of custom field in <p> tags
                            $credit=get_post_meta($post->ID,'Credit',true);
                            if($credit != '') {
                            echo '<p>'. $credit .'</p>';
                            } else {
                            echo ' ';
                            }
                            ?>
                      </figcaption>
                    </figure>

                    <?php
                    $sub_title=get_post_meta($post->ID,'subtitle',true);
                    if($sub_title != '') {
                    echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'<span> / '. $sub_title . ' / ' . get_the_time('l jS F') .'</span></h1>';
                    } else {
                    echo '<h1>'. get_the_title() .'<span> / ' . get_the_time('l jS F') .'</span></h1>';
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php the_content(''); ?>

                    <div class="a-options">
                        <a href="#post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="comments scrollto">Comment</a>

                        <!-- share -->
                        <div class="share-button">
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <div class="facebook">                          

                                    <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="twitter">

                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-via="kettlesyard" data-related="kettlesyard" data-hashtags="kettlesyard">Tweet</a>
                                    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

                                </div>

                                <div class="pinterest">
                                    <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <span class="pseudo-button">&#043; Share</span>
                         </div> <!--! /share -->

                    </div><!--! /a-options -->


                    <?php if ( in_category( 'contact' ) ) : // Display nothing ?>

                        <?php // Else, show comments
                        else : ?>

                            <?php global $withcomments;
                            $withcomments = 1;
                            comments_template(); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                  </article>

                  <?php } ?>




                <?php endwhile; ?>



                <div id="next-prev-wrap" class="nextprev"><?php next_posts_link(); ?> <?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div>




                <?php endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is the fact that you're using `query_posts`.  That function isn't meant for creating *new* queries to the database; instead, it's used to modify the existing global query.

Read up [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) and [here](http://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/) for more information on what you can use instead.

Second, there is just some strange code in your template that, honestly, shouldn't have worked in the first place.  This line:

```
$args= array(
    'category_name' => $cat->slug, 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'cat' => '-12',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
);
```

... is referencing variables that I don't see elsewhere in your code.  Namely, `$cat` and `$post`.  The fact that you're referencing `$post` at all tells me you either have some other query higher up in the page, or are inside another loop ... in either case, calling `query_posts()` will definitely hurt.

Also, the minute differences between your local installation and network installation can also play a part.  If you aren't using the exact same versions of WP, PHP, MySQL, etc across both systems, strange differences like this can crop up.

Comment: Yeah I have another loop above it that outputs the content from the current post. Shall I link you up to my full code? Would that help?

Comment: Please always link to the full code.

Comment: Here's the link to the code in full: http://pastebin.com/dtiSHUYP Its also added to the post

Comment: Any ideas @EAMann?